# Bootstrap columns unwanted shifting on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap columns arranged to display product info. Each div features 4 hover effects which I've added. The problem arises at the "col-sm" breakpoint where the first div wraps underneath the others. When hovering over the last top div, the wrapped div shifts around the layout. I've tried commenting out each hover effect to locate the issues, however it appears any change on hover will cause the div to shift.

Without any hover effects, the div doesn't shift at all.
I've tried using the "clear" property but that didn't produce the desired result, however I'm still open to suggestions.

Please run the snippet I've provided on full screen and at just under 992px.
Thanks in advance.

```css
.store .store-product {
  text-align: center;
}

.store .store-product .thumbnail {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
}

.store .store-product .caption {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.store .store-product .product-img {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.store .store-product .product-name {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.store .store-product .product-price {
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.store .store-product .product-actions {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.store .store-product .product-actions a {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.store .store-product:hover .product-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.store .store-product:hover .thumbnail {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 2px #ddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 2px #ddd;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 2px #ddd;
}

.store .store-product:hover .thumbnail .caption {
    border: 0;
}

.store .store-product:hover .product-actions {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row store">
  <div class="col-xs-12 store-logo">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/Walmart_logo.svg_03.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Store row /end -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from trial and error I was able to determine your issue was with the following style:

```
.store .store-product:hover .thumbnail .caption {
  border: 0;
}
```

Changing that class to the following seems to fix the problem. Unfortunately, I have no idea why.

```
.store .store-product:hover .thumbnail .caption {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```css
.store .store-product {
  text-align: center;
}

.store .store-product .thumbnail {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
}

.store .store-product .caption {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.store .store-product .product-img {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.store .store-product .product-name {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.store .store-product .product-price {
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.store .store-product .product-actions {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.store .store-product .product-actions a {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.store .store-product:hover .product-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.store .store-product:hover .thumbnail {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 2px #ddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 2px #ddd;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 2px #ddd;
}

.store .store-product:hover .thumbnail .caption {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.store .store-product:hover .product-actions {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row store">
  <div class="col-xs-12 store-logo">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/Walmart_logo.svg_03.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 store-product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="product-img" src="img/camera.png" alt="product">
      <div class="caption">
        <p class="product-name">Canon EOS 80D + EF-S 18-135mm IS nano USM</p>
        <p class="product-price">$1 300</p>
        <p class="product-actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> add to cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Store row /end -->
```

Comment: Wow - that works great and is better aesthetically for the transition. Changing the borders color is a much better alternative rather than removing the border entirely, although its odd something like that would have been the issue. Thanks alot!

Comment: Sure thing, I wish I could give you an explanation as to why this is happening as removing a border in one column shouldn't cause other columns to behave differently. Either way I am glad this solution works for you. Good luck on your future coding.

Comment: Just clicked in my head... Bootstrap 3 will try to place the next wrapping column under the shortest column above. In this case, removing the border makes that column 1px shorter than the rest and causes this behavior.

Comment: This all makes sense now. Thanks again!